# Android: Pass JSON string to the service class "PostData"

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to post data to the localhost server (WAMP) with the aid of the HttpURLConnection api. I implemented it with the help of IntentService but I do not know how can I pass the data "JSON string" from MainActivity to the DataPost class.

This part is being called from onLocationChanged methode in the inner class "MyLocationListener" in the MainActivity:

```
        String jSONString = convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, formatted);

        Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostData.class);
        intent3.putExtra("json_data", jSONString);
        PendingIntent pintent3 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent3, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm3 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // for 30 mint 60*60*1000
        alarm3.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000, pintent3);

        startService(intent3);
```

PostData class:

```
   package com.bustracker;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;

public class PostData extends IntentService {
    String jSONString;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public PostData() {
        super("some");

    }

    public String getjSONString() {
        return jSONString;
    }

    public void setjSONString(String jSONString) {
        this.jSONString = jSONString;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_data");
        try {
            // This is the ip address of my laptop wifi because I am running the
            // app in my device and I want to send the data to the localhost
            // server(WAMP).
            URL myUrl = new URL("http://192.168.x.x/webservice");
            HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                    .openConnection();
            myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            myConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            myConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            myConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            myConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            myConnection.connect();
            // create data output stream
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    myConnection.getOutputStream());
            // write to the output stream from the string
            wr.writeBytes(jSONString);
            wr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why is there a Asynctask in Intent service?

Comment: Ok I will get ride of it later :) I thought it would work in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not know how can I pass the data "JSON string" from MainActivity
>   to the DataPost class

Use `Intent.putExtra` to pass `jSONString` String to `IntentService` :

```
....
// add jSONString to intent using any key
intent3.putExtra("json_data",jSONString);
startService(intent3);
```

Now use `intent.getStringExtra` in `onHandleIntent` to get String:

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_data");
    }
```

**Note:** No need to use `AsyncTask` in `IntentService` because  *onHandleIntent method is invoked on the worker thread with a request to process*

so use `onHandleIntent` method for making http request

Comment: is this "intent" here another one than  "intent3"?

Comment: What I have not down-voted it? And I cant do that too since I have just 92 points ;)

Comment: can you please take a look at my updated question's code I changed it to your approach but jSONString is getting null in the `onHandleIntent`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use putExtra like this,

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostData.class);
x="3";
y="A";
i.putExtra(ValueX, x);
i.putExtra(ValueY, y);
startActivity(i);
```

see how the client will receive and try to parse, it should not be hard.